# C# property get private set

Tags: c#, forms, class

How can I know which one of the following I need to use:

```
public int Dollar { get; set };
public int Dollar { get; private set };
private int Dollar { get; set };
private int Dollar { get; private set };
```

When I'm programming I am always asking myself which one I should use. Anyone that can explain me how I can know which one I need to use?

Comment: how are you using Dollar?..

Comment: The third and fourth options you provided are the same.

Comment: For example to show it on the screen.

Comment: @xVizzi: The options have nothing to do with "showing something on a screen" and everything to do with the design of the object itself.  Do other objects need to observe the value of `Dollar`?  Do other objects need to modify the value of `Dollar`?  That's all.

Comment: What's the point of disliking this question? really.

Comment: The question is not a matter of like or dislike, it's more a matter of some basic things that you could have found easily doing a google search. Or from a .net book on how to Access Properties, How to Create or declare properties, and what is an `Auto Property`.. outside of that `Sayse` answer explains it all quite clearly

Comment: @xVizzi - In answer to your actual question... It depends how you are using Dollar and what scope it requires throughout your application, all 5 answers below should give you an idea of what you should create depending on your requirements

Answer (score 11):

```
public int Dollar { get; set };
```

Dollar can be retrieved and set throughout the application

```
public int Dollar { get; private set };
```

Dollar can be retrieved throughout the application but only set from the class containing it

```
private int Dollar { get; set };
```

Only the class containing Dollar can use Dollar

**EDIT**

Note: A public field can also be accessed outside of the application if knowledge of how to implement it is known. `Internal` will make it so only the application can use the property

**EDIT 2**

As other have pointed out the following is a compiler error.

```
private int Dollar { get; private set };
```

> The accessibility modifier of the
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Program.Dollar.set' accessor must be more
>   restrictive than the property or indexer

Comment: Note that the very last case is kinda redundant. The property is already `private` so there's no point marking the setter as `private` too.

Comment: @MattBurland - I've left it as such incase OP is reading code that has been refactored etc :)

Comment: Won't the last one `private int Dollar { get; private set };` actually cause a compile error?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Yes it does, I didnt realize, I've never tried implementing anything like it (will add an update)

Answer (score 3):

Does any other code outside of your class need to be able to access `Dollar`? If no, then you should use:

```
private int Dollar { get; set; }
```

Note, there's no point setting the setter to private if the property is private. You might also question whether or not you need a property at all and whether a private field might be more appropriate.

If other code ONLY needs read access then:

```
public int Dollar { get; private set; }
```

If other code needs to be able to both read and set `Dollar`:

```
public int Dollar { get; set; }
```

If you need derived classes to be able to access it (but not non-derived classes), replace `private` with `protected`

Answer (score 2):

See the comments below

```
1) public int Dollar { get; set; }
```

you can access this property from anywhere in the application.Get and Set both available.

```
2) public int Dollar { get; private set; }
```

you can access this property from anywhere in the application but only Get is available. You can't set property value.

```
3) private int Dollar { get; set; }
```

You can access this only inside the class.

```
4) private int Dollar { get; private set; }
```

Syntax error.

Comment: @Sayse: It is a compilation error though, `The accessibility modifier of the 'MyClass.Test.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'MyClass.Test'`

Comment: @Cemafor - Ah so it is, I tested for syntax but never compiled ^.^

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, it depends on the usage.

If you are very rich, make your Dollars private, otherwise the lower classes would be jealous of your property. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dollar such that you need the fields to be public, then go public. Otherwise, if you are accessing Dollar only in the class its defined in, use private.

My rule of thumb is make everything private unless there is some demand that forces the field to be public.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only used internally - make it private (or just a private variable, not a property).

If it's read externally but should only be written internally, make it public with a private setter.

Otherwise, make it public.